# extract name from specific occurence of a pattern in a large file

Tags: python, r, bash, string-matching

I have a FASTA file which is basically a text file for depicting biological sequence data (https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Web&PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=BlastHelp) having more than 10,000 FASTA sequences (starting with >). The beginning of the file looks like:

```
>Gene A
GAACTACACAAACGTAAAATGTAAAACAAAGGTATAAATTCCAGAAGTTGGACAGACATATATAGACAGCACATATATTA
TCTTTATTTTTTTATGTATGATAACATTAAATATAACGTTCAACAATT
>Gene B
GAACTACACAAACGTAAAATGTAAAACAAAGGTATAAATTCCAGAAGTTGGACAGACATATATAGACAGCACATATATTA
TCTTTATTTTTTTATGTATGATAACATTAAATATAACGTTCAACAATTACACCGTTAGCAGTGTGAGCAAAAACGATTAA
AAAGTAAATATTATAAAAGCCCTC
>Gene C
AACAACAAATTGCCATCTACCCGTTTGAATCCTGTAATAATAACTTGCCCAGATTTGCTGCAGCATACTCCTAGAGTTGG
GCTGGGTGGCCCACACAAGCGATAATAACATTTAACAATTGTTTGATATATGTACTTTTTTTTAAGTTTTTTTCTCCTCG
TACTTGCCTTCCAAAAACTCGTTAGCTTTGTACACATACGCCTTTAATTAAAATACTGATAGATGCGTACCACTTACGTC
ATTAGAAAAAGTCACCAAAAGGAAAAATATGGACGACACAAGAACGAGGAGATCTAAGCCACTCGTAGACCACTAAGCAC
AAAATACCCGAAAAATATAACTGATATGATTGCCAACTACCCTGCGACTATGTAAACCCAACCTTCCCCCCTCCTTTACC
CTCTTATTCAAATCGACGCGTGTGTAGAAGATACACTTATTATATTTTTTTTCTGAGATACAATTATAAACACAAAAACG
ACTTTTAACTATATATTAAATAAAAACAAAAGGAAAAACATAATAATTT
>Gene D
AACAACAAATTGCCATCTACCCGTTTGAATCCTGTAATAATAACTTGCCCAGATTTGCTGCAGCATACTCCTAGAGTTGG
GCTGGGTGGCCCACACAAGCGATAATAACATTTAACAATTGTTTGATATATGTACTTTTTTTTAAGTTTTTTTCTCCTCG
TACTTGCCTTCCAAAAACTCGTTAGCTTTGTACACATACGCCTTTAATTAAAATACTGATAGATGCGTACCACTTACGTC
ATTAGAAAAAGTCACCAAAAGGAAAAATATGGACGACACAAGAACGAGGAGATCTAAGCCACTCGTAGACCACTAAGCAC
AAAATACCCGAAAAATATAACTGATATGATTGCCAACTACCCTGCGACTATGTAAACCCAACCTTCCCCCCTCCTTTACC
CTCTTATTCAAATCGACGCGTGTGTAGAAGATACACTTATTATATTTTTTTTCTGAGATACAATTATAAACACAAAAACG
ACTTTTAACTATATATTAAATAAAAACAAAAGGAAAAACATAATAATTT
```

and so on for approximately 10,000 genes.
I want to:

1. find which of the genes contain a specific pattern (CTTTGTA)
2. how many times is this pattern present in that gene?
3. export the list of gene names containing the pattern with the frequency of the pattern.

Any solution in Bash or Python (or R) is appreciated.

P.S. What I have tried thus far but didn't work: extracting genes with their sequences into separate files and then grep for the pattern in separate files. I could, however, not generate these separate files. I used

```
grep '^>' file.txt > new_file.txt
```

but the output I get is a single file containing all the gene names only.

Comment: Welcome to SO @FLYGuy, if the answer helped - Please mark it as correct and consider an upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer so that it outputs the gene name and not the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution with R using `stringi` package. Since there is no single text file or similar to be accessed as reproducible example I have used used `cat()`and `readlines()` to read a temporary representing a copy of the lines you provided. Please also check the timing benchmark, might be of interest for large files.

```
library(stringi)

cat(">Gene A
GAACTACACAAACGTAAAATGTAAAACAAAGGTATAAATTCCAGAAGTTGGACAGACATATATAGACAGCACATATATTA
    TCTTTATTTTTTTATGTATGATAACATTAAATATAACGTTCAACAATT
    >Gene B
    GAACTACACAAACGTAAAATGTAAAACAAAGGTATAAATTCCAGAAGTTGGACAGACATATATAGACAGCACATATATTA
    TCTTTATTTTTTTATGTATGATAACATTAAATATAACGTTCAACAATTACACCGTTAGCAGTGTGAGCAAAAACGATTAA
    AAAGTAAATATTATAAAAGCCCTC
    >Gene C
    AACAACAAATTGCCATCTACCCGTTTGAATCCTGTAATAATAACTTGCCCAGATTTGCTGCAGCATACTCCTAGAGTTGG
    GCTGGGTGGCCCACACAAGCGATAATAACATTTAACAATTGTTTGATATATGTACTTTTTTTTAAGTTTTTTTCTCCTCG
    TACTTGCCTTCCAAAAACTCGTTAGCTTTGTACACATACGCCTTTAATTAAAATACTGATAGATGCGTACCACTTACGTC
    ATTAGAAAAAGTCACCAAAAGGAAAAATATGGACGACACAAGAACGAGGAGATCTAAGCCACTCGTAGACCACTAAGCAC
    AAAATACCCGAAAAATATAACTGATATGATTGCCAACTACCCTGCGACTATGTAAACCCAACCTTCCCCCCTCCTTTACC
    CTCTTATTCAAATCGACGCGTGTGTAGAAGATACACTTATTATATTTTTTTTCTGAGATACAATTATAAACACAAAAACG
    ACTTTTAACTATATATTAAATAAAAACAAAAGGAAAAACATAATAATTT
    >Gene D
    AACAACAAATTGCCATCTACCCGTTTGAATCCTGTAATAATAACTTGCCCAGATTTGCTGCAGCATACTCCTAGAGTTGG
    GCTGGGTGGCCCACACAAGCGATAATAACATTTAACAATTGTTTGATATATGTACTTTTTTTTAAGTTTTTTTCTCCTCG
    TACTTGCCTTCCAAAAACTCGTTAGCTTTGTACACATACGCCTTTAATTAAAATACTGATAGATGCGTACCACTTACGTC
    ATTAGAAAAAGTCACCAAAAGGAAAAATATGGACGACACAAGAACGAGGAGATCTAAGCCACTCGTAGACCACTAAGCAC
    AAAATACCCGAAAAATATAACTGATATGATTGCCAACTACCCTGCGACTATGTAAACCCAACCTTCCCCCCTCCTTTACC
    CTCTTATTCAAATCGACGCGTGTGTAGAAGATACACTTATTATATTTTTTTTCTGAGATACAATTATAAACACAAAAACG
    ACTTTTAACTATATATTAAATAAAAACAAAAGGAAAAACATAATAATTT
", file = "tempfile.txt")

genes <- readLines("tempfile.txt", n=-1)
unlink("tempfile.txt")

genes <- unlist(stri_split_fixed(paste(genes, collapse = " "), ">"))
genes <- genes[ genes != ""]

genenames <- unlist(stri_extract_all_regex(genes, "Gene \\w+"))
genes <- stri_replace_all_fixed(genes, genenames, "")
names(genes) <- genenames

genes <- gsub("\\s+", "", genes, perl = T) 

gene_pattern_freq <- function(str, patterns) {

  res <- sapply(patterns, function(p) {

    stringi::stri_count_fixed(str, p)

  }, USE.NAMES = T)

  rownames(res) <- names(str)

  return(res)
}

searchpatterns <- c("AA", "GT", "GAACTACACAAACGTAAAATGTAAAACAAAGGTATAAA")
result <- gene_pattern_freq(genes, searchpatterns)
result
#        AA GT GAACTACACAAACGTAAAATGTAAAACAAAGGTATAAA
# Gene A 14  6                                      1
# Gene B 21 10                                      1
# Gene C 52 18                                      0
# Gene D 52 18                                      0

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(gene_pattern_freq(genes, searchpatterns))
# Unit: microseconds
# expr                                      min     lq    mean   median   uq     max   neval
# gene_pattern_freq(genes, searchpatterns) 68.687 77.371 123.438 78.161 79.345 4479.19   100

#export
write.csv(result, file = "../mypath/gene_pattern_freq_result.csv" )
```

Comment: Well, this will work with those occurrences, but not with the file. Unless he pastes the content of the file into the code, declaring each sequence as a variable and cleaning it up the way you did. You should probably post a solution that opens the file in question and uses its content instead of hardcoded variables.

Comment: @alexisdevarennes The link posted did provide a text file as reproducible example or did I miss anything?

Comment: Well in the description, it says: having more than 10,000 FASTA sequences. So I think its faaaar larger than what is displayed on the website. I also could not find this text file.

Comment: @Manuel Bickel: The link I posted is just a description of the FASTA format. My actual file, as correctly pointed out by alexisdevarennes, has more than 10,000 entries.

Comment: @alexisdevarennes Updated my answer, data now is a copy of the exemplary lines. I have also added a benchmark and would be interested in benchmarks of your solutions for the replacement part.

Comment: @Manuel Bickel: Thanks for the solution. Works nicely. Here are the benchmarking results- Unit: milliseconds
                                     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 gene_pattern_freq(genes, searchpatterns) 82.72488 83.26413 84.08552 83.80906 84.29342 87.87725   100

Answer (score 0):

```
sequences = open('fastafile.txt').read().split('>')  # Creates a list of sequences.

needle = 'CTTTGTA'

occurrences = {}

for sequence in sequences:
   occ = sequence.count(needle)  # Returns the number of times the substring occurs in the string sequence.
   if occ:  # If greater than 0, create an entry in our dictionary. The sequence being the key and the count the value.
      occurrences[sequence] = occ

output = []

sorted_occurrences = sorted(occurrences.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))  # Sort the dictionary by length, so sequences with the highest occurrence of the needle appear at the top.

for seq, occ_count in sorted_occurrences.iteritems():
    gene_name, sequence = seq.split('\n')
    formatted_line = '{gene_name} - {occ_count}'.format(gene_name=gene_name, occ_count=str(occ_count))  # Format the lines the way you want.
    output.append(formatted_line)  

with open('occurences.txt') as o_f:
    o_f.write('\n'.join(output))
```

Comment: Hi @alexisdevarennes. Thanks for the possible solution. However, on running the script, I get a NameError: name 'sorted_occurrences' is not defined. If I don't sort and just try to get the list (by # on the sorted_occurrences) then I get: gene_name, sequence = seq.split('\n')
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: not working!! still the same NameError and the ValueError